# Подгон изображения по размерам jLabel

Tags: java, swing, gui

Нужно чтобы изображение которое загружалось jLable в приняло размеры такие как сам компонент jLabel
Вот код, что здесь нужно добавить?

```
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    url_image = file.toString();
                    System.out.println(url_image);
                    icon = new ImageIcon(file.toString());
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.toString());
                    photo_label.setIcon(icon);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовый метод:

```
/**
     * Resizes image to panel's width and height.
     * @param img Source image.
     * @param panel Panel with new sizes.
     * @return resized image.
     */
    public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, JPanel panel){
        Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);     
        img = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: то ето для Jpanel  а мне нужно для jlabel

Comment: @user221117 замените 'JPanel panel' на 'JLabel label' в аргументе и все переменные 'panel' на 'label'